# How can I modify the apalike bibliography style to remove parentheses of year?

Tags: natbib, apa-style, brackets

I am using apalike biblography style, I would like to remove the parentheses from the year, so that the reference should look like:

> Aggarwal, R., Kearney, C., and Lucey, B. 2012. Gravity and culture in
>   foreign portfolio investment. Journal of Banking & Finance,
>   36(2):525–538.

Instead of what I currently have

> Aggarwal, R., Kearney, C., and Lucey, B. (2012). Gravity and culture
>   in foreign portfolio investment. Journal of Banking & Finance,
>   36(2):525–538.

Here is the code I have currently:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}    
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{csquotes}    
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}    
\section{introduction}    
blah blah    
\bibliographystyle{apalike}    
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}    
\end{document}
```

I saw a solutions here but it is under `apacite` which does not apply to `apalike`. Any one knows what I should do with `apalike`? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Comment: It should apply to all types including article, paper and book. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make a copy of `apalike.bst` and rename it something sensible like `apalike-noparen`. In the `.bst` file you will find the following function:

```
FUNCTION {output.year.check}
{ year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { write$
      " (" year * extra.label * ")" *
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
}
```

Replace this code with the following, to remove the parentheses:

```
FUNCTION {output.year.check}
{ year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { write$
      " " year * extra.label * 
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
}
```

Place the edited `.bst` file in the same file as your document, or in the `bibtex/bst` folder of your local `texmf` folder (if you plan to use it more generally). Then use `\bibliographystyle{apalike-noparen}` in your document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am new to latex and would you pls suggest where I can find the "apalike.bst" file? I don't see it in the same folder of my file. I cannot find the texmf folder either.(I tried to check my TeX folder, but cannot find texmf). I am currently using Texstudio to create my Latex document. Any ideas about where and how I can find the file? Thank you.

Comment: @Catherine From the command line, you can use `kpsewhich apalike.bst` and this should return the whole path of the file. Alternatively you could download a copy from CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base

Comment: Alan, thank you for your detailed guide, but how can I create a .bst file? I tried to download the copy and paste it into my Texstudio window but it cannot be saved as .bst file. Also, I tried to check whehter I can find the apalike.bst  by type enter /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/ in the Finder (I am using a Mac), but it is strange that the bst folder is an empty folder. So I am still struggling with it, any ideas? Or is there any way that I can skip using .bst, but instead using something like adding \renewcommand{}. Thank you!

Comment: @Catherine In TeXStudio, when you choose Save As, there is a dropdown menu of file types. If you choose `All Files (*)` you can save any file type, so you can save as `.bst`.  BTW, your MacTeX is very old; you might want to consider installing the latest version at some point.  To open the file directly from the terminal on a Mac, you can type `open -a TeXStudio \`kpsewhich apalike.bst\``

Comment: Thank you Alan, finally got the problem solved.