# Modify apalike reference list

Tags: natbib, apa-style

I am currently using the `natbib` package with the `apalike` style.
The reference list that it generate are now like this:

[image]

How do I remove the parentheses around the year fields and the vertical space between each line to look like this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information on how to remove the parentheses around the `year` field when employing the `apalike` bibliography style, please check out the posting [How can I modify the apalike bibliography style to remove parentheses of year?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516840/5001)

To minimize the vertical separation between the formatted bibliographic entries, issue the command

```
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}
```

in the preamble, *after* loading the `natbib` package.